# mount LUKS encrypted partition as read write

Tags: mount, encryption, luks

I have img file that's contains LUKS encrypted image.

I successfully mount the encrypted partition, but it's mount as read-only

what I do is:

```
sudo losetup -P /dev/loop0 myimg.img
udisksctl unlock -b /dev/loop0p1
mount /dev/dm-0 /mnt
   mount:/dev/dm-0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
```

I tried to mount using the following:

```
mount -o remount,rw /dev/dm-0 /mnt

mount: /mnt not mounted or bad option
       In some cases useful info is found is syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

in dmesg i got:

```
EXT$-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts:(null)
```

or

```
mount -o remount,rw /dev/dm-0
mount: cannot remount /dev/dm-0 read-write, is write-protected
```

also I tried to use e2fsck as root:

```
e2fsck /dev/dm-0
e2fsck: Operation not permitted while trying to open /dev/dm-0
You must r/w access to the filesystem or be root
```

So how I can get write access to this partition ?

Comment: This does not appear to be an issue with `mount`, the device is already write protected according to the first output. Now the question becomes why is `/dev/dm-0` write protected?